# checkbox multilist with hybrid clicking selection on label or on checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have this scheme for multiselection of checkboxes, and I need `p.label` to trigger the `.item` checkbox (child of it);

But my JS script is working only when `.labels` are clicked, it selects/unselects the checkboxes, but **when I click directly on the checkboxes** inputs, I need that the checkboxes have the normal behavior of a checkbox, and ignore the `onclick` event added to all labels.

**In short:** I need the items in the list to be selectable through the label or directly in the box. How can I a fix my script to prevent colisions that are happening?

```js
let fruits_labels = document.querySelectorAll("#fruits .label");
let fruits_items = document.querySelectorAll("#fruits .label .item"); 

fruits_labels.forEach((label, index) => {

  label.onclick = (event) => {

    console.log("index: " + index);

    fruits_items[index].checked = (fruits_items[index].checked == true) ? false : true;

  }

});

let colors_labels = document.querySelectorAll("#colors .label");
let colors_items = document.querySelectorAll("#colors .label .item");

colors_labels.forEach((label, index) => {

  label.onclick = (event) => {

    console.log("index: " + index);

    colors_items[index].checked = (colors_items[index].checked == true) ? false : true;

  }

});
```

```css
div.container{ margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black; }

div.container p.label { margin: 0; padding: 4px 8px; display: flex; align-items: center; border: 1px solid magenta; }

div.container p.label:hover { background-color: yellow; }

div.container p.label input[type=checkbox].item{ margin-right: 6px; }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="fruits">
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">APPLE</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">BANANA</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">KIWI</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">LEMON</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">ORANGE</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="colors">
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">RED</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">GREEN</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">BLUE</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could use labels and they would work nicely, as Ostone0 described, I will show you how your script can be fixed, so you will learn about propagation and `stopPropagation`, but you should not overcomplicate yourself and you should aim to simplify your code once your tests work.

```js
let fruits_labels = document.querySelectorAll("#fruits .label");
let fruits_items = document.querySelectorAll("#fruits .label .item"); 

fruits_labels.forEach((label, index) => {

  label.onclick = (event) => {

    console.log("index: " + index);

    fruits_items[index].checked = (fruits_items[index].checked == true) ? false : true;

  }
  
  label.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      console.log("index: " + index);
      event.stopPropagation();
  });

});

let colors_labels = document.querySelectorAll("#colors .label");
let colors_items = document.querySelectorAll("#colors .label .item");

colors_labels.forEach((label, index) => {

  label.onclick = (event) => {

    console.log("index: " + index);

    colors_items[index].checked = (colors_items[index].checked == true) ? false : true;

  }

  label.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      console.log("index: " + index);
      event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
div.container{ margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black; }

div.container p.label { margin: 0; padding: 4px 8px; display: flex; align-items: center; border: 1px solid magenta; }

div.container p.label:hover { background-color: yellow; }

div.container p.label input[type=checkbox].item{ margin-right: 6px; }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="fruits">
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">APPLE</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">BANANA</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">KIWI</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">LEMON</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">ORANGE</p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="colors">
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">RED</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">GREEN</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">BLUE</p>
</div>
```

Events are bubbling, that is, the event of a tag **propagates** an event to its parent which propagates one to its parent and so on. So, when you click on the checkbox, then its default click handler changes the `checked` value and propagates to the parent, which has an event that negates the `checked` value. So, you can use `stopPropagation` to avoid the bubbling from happening.

Answer (score 3):

Don't re-invent the wheel. Your desired behaviour can be achieved natively with a [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element:

```css
label { margin: 0; padding: 4px 8px; display: flex; align-items: center; border: 1px solid magenta; width: 200px; }
label:hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="fruits">
  <label for='APPLE' class="label"><input id='APPLE' class="item" type="checkbox" />APPLE</label>
  <label for='BANANA' class="label"><input id='BANANA' class="item" type="checkbox" />BANANA</label>
  <label for='KIWI' class="label"><input id='KIWI' class="item" type="checkbox" />KIWI</label>
  <label for='LEMON' class="label"><input id='LEMON' class="item" type="checkbox" />LEMON</label>
  <label for='ORANGE' class="label"><input id='ORANGE' class="item" type="checkbox" />ORANGE</label>
</div>
```

---

If you, for some reason can't use the above, another option would be to check the `firstChild` of the click's `event.target`. If that's a `checkbox`, you'll need to toggle it:

```js
[ ...document.querySelectorAll('.label') ].forEach(l => {
    l.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (e.target.firstChild?.type === 'checkbox') {
            e.target.firstChild.checked = !e.target.firstChild.checked;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div.container{ margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black; }
div.container p.label { margin: 0; padding: 4px 8px; display: flex; align-items: center; border: 1px solid magenta; }
div.container p.label:hover { background-color: yellow; }
div.container p.label input[type=checkbox].item{ margin-right: 6px; }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="fruits">
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">APPLE</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">BANANA</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">KIWI</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">LEMON</p>
  <p class="label"><input class="item" type="checkbox">ORANGE</p>
</div>
```

Comment: but it's for many many items, i don´t need to have an `id` attribute all `<input>`'s of the list, makes no sense to me at all ; How can i do the same with a example that i provided as `<p><input type="checkbox"></p>` ? is it possible ? I want re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Please see my edit + second snippet. This seems like the most dynamic solution.